# bash sort and format text output

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed

i'm new at bash scripting,

I need to format this text, it has several data, what i need is to group similar Applications ant it's PID to get the total connections to different databases per application.

Text 1.txt

```
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 12
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_3 IP: 1.2.3.3 Current: 3
App: App_1 PID: 23996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 10
App: App_1 PID: 23996 DBsrv: DBSRV_5 IP: 1.2.3.5 Current: 12
App: App_3 PID: 25996 DBsrv: DBSRV_7 IP: 1.2.3.7 Current: 15
App: App_3 PID: 27196 DBsrv: DBSRV_8 IP: 1.2.3.8 Current: 16
App: App_3 PID: 27196 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 12
App: App_2 PID: 28996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_2 PID: 28996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 19
App: App_4 PID: 21996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_5 PID: 20996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 1
App: App_5 PID: 20996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.4 Current: 1
```

Desired Output:

```
App: App_1 PID: 27996
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 12
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_3 IP: 1.2.3.3 Current: 3
--
App: App_1 PID: 23996
App: App_1 PID: 23996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 10
App: App_1 PID: 23996 DBsrv: DBSRV_5 IP: 1.2.3.5 Current: 12
--
App: App_3 PID: 25996 
App: App_3 PID: 25996 DBsrv: DBSRV_7 IP: 1.2.3.7 Current: 15
--
App: App_3 PID: 27196
App: App_3 PID: 27196 DBsrv: DBSRV_8 IP: 1.2.3.8 Current: 16
App: App_3 PID: 27196 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 12
--
App: App_2 PID: 28966
App: App_2 PID: 28996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_2 PID: 28996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 19
--
App: App_4 PID: 21966
App: App_4 PID: 21996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
--
App: App_5 PID: 20966
App: App_5 PID: 20996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 1
App: App_5 PID: 20996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.4 Current: 1
```

Comment: Are connections to the same app with the same PID always grouped together, as in your sample data? You say 'total connections'. Is grouping enough, or do you need to _sum_ the connection counts?

Comment: Hi, no , the connections are already grouped, what i need is to group by the application name, and by it's PID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk script:

```
awk 'p!=$4{c=$4;print "App: "$2" PID "p}1' data.txt
```

The script checks if the content the PID changes. If so, it prints the header and puts the new PID value to the variable `p` - pid. All lines will be printed, in `awk` just a `1` because 1 evaluates to true and `print` is the default per-line-action in awk.

---

I see my above command is missing the `--` separator. You can modify it a little bit to achive that. I've added a new variable `s` - separator. It will get printed before the header, except if it is the first line because `s` gets initialized after printing the first header and will be empty before:

```
awk 'p!=$4{p=$4;print s"App: "$2" PID "p;s="--\n"}1' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
awk '
BEGIN { SUBSEP = FS }
{
    pids[$1,$2,$3,$4] = ((pids[$1,$2,$3,$4]) ? pids[$1,$2,$3,$4] RS $0 : $0)
}
END {
    for(pid in pids) {
        print pid; print pids[pid]
    }
}' file

App: App_2 PID: 28996
App: App_2 PID: 28996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_2 PID: 28996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 19
App: App_3 PID: 27196
App: App_3 PID: 27196 DBsrv: DBSRV_8 IP: 1.2.3.8 Current: 16
App: App_3 PID: 27196 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 12
App: App_1 PID: 27996
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 12
App: App_1 PID: 27996 DBsrv: DBSRV_3 IP: 1.2.3.3 Current: 3
App: App_4 PID: 21996
App: App_4 PID: 21996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 1
App: App_3 PID: 25996
App: App_3 PID: 25996 DBsrv: DBSRV_7 IP: 1.2.3.7 Current: 15
App: App_5 PID: 20996
App: App_5 PID: 20996 DBsrv: DBSRV_2 IP: 1.2.3.2 Current: 1
App: App_5 PID: 20996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.4 Current: 1
App: App_1 PID: 23996
App: App_1 PID: 23996 DBsrv: DBSRV_1 IP: 1.2.3.1 Current: 10
App: App_1 PID: 23996 DBsrv: DBSRV_5 IP: 1.2.3.5 Current: 12
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it's great and it prints what i wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2 $4 != last { if(NR > 1) { print "--" }; print $1 $2 $3 $4; last = $2 $4; firs }
     { print }' < text1.txt
```

Comment: Promising, but you're trying to use single quotes inside single quotes, you have an orphaned `firs`, and your group header is missing separators between fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ID in `cat Text1.txt | awk '{print $4}' | sort -u`
do 
    cat Text1.txt | grep "$ID" | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4}' | head -n 1
    cat Text1.txt | grep "$ID"
    echo '--'
done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), please. Btw, useless uses of `cat` too. Not mentioning a very inefficient method.

Comment: yet, it worked well , it outputs what i needed, thanks @damgad

Comment: @MarcosPousada There are lots of good answers here and you chose the worst one!

Comment: hehe, no i'm testing everyone of them.. it's the least i can do ...@gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 0):

An annotated `awk` solution:

```
awk '{
 if (prevPid != $4) {  # New group starting? (new PID?)
     # Output group header, prefixed by "--" line, unless this is the 1st line.
   print (NR > 1 ? "--\n" : "") $1, $2, $3, $4
     # Save PID for next iteration.
   prevPid=$4
 }
 print  # (Also) print each input line as is.
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re '1{:a;h;G;s/ DBsrv[^\n]*//;t};G;/(PID: [0-9]+ ).*\n.*\1/{P;d};i\--' -e 's/\n.*//;ta' file
```

This uses the hold space to hold each pid change and compares it against subsequent lines.